# Skip files in loop which already have FINAL in their name

Tags: bash

I want to change the CODEC H264 to H265, the archives which have H264, they have the following format:
archive.mp4

and once is changed the archive has this format:
archiveFINAL.mp4

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
find *.mp4 | while read -r file; do 
if [ "${file%.*}" != "${file%.*}FINAL" ]; then
    ffmpeg -i "${file%.*}".mp4 -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 "${file%.*}FINAL".mp4
else
    echo "There is not archives to convert"
fi;
done
```

I made test with archiveFINAL.mp4 and the script works when in theory if the name is archiveFINAL.mp4 it doesn't have to work.
The problem is the code works without discriminate between archive.mp4 and archiveFINAL.mp4. And I don't want to do it if the name of the archive finish in FINAL.mp

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional probably doesn't do what you want, and looks much too complex anyway.

```sh
find *.mp4 | while read -r file; do 
  if [ "${file%FINAL.mp4}" = "$file" ]; then
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 "${file%.mp4}FINAL".mp4
  else
    echo "$file is already converted" >&2
  fi
done
```

I would probably use a `case` statement instead, but this attempts to change as little as possible. The `case` syntax might look scary if you are not familiar with it;

```sh
  case $file in
   *FINAL.mp4) echo "$file is already converted" >&2;;
   *) ffmpeg ...;;
  esac
```

By the way, notice that this will recurse into subdirectories; if that's not desired, you want simply `for file in *.mp4; do`...

Answer (score 0):

To check if the file name ends with "FINAL.mp4", you can just do it like this:

```
echo "$file_name" | grep -Eq '.+FINAL\.mp4$'
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    // do what you want here
fi
```

Comment: `if echo "$file_name" | grep -Eq '.+Final\.mp4$'; then ....; fi` Will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find`. It's the tool to... find stuff.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.mp4' '!' -name '*FINAL.mp4' |
while IFS= read -r line; do
   ffmpeg -i "${file%.*}".mp4 -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 "${file%.*}FINAL".mp4
done
```

The

```
find *.mp4
```

is equal to

```
find somefile.mp4 otherfile.mp4 otherfile.mp4 ....
```

It's not using `find` as intended at all - `*.mp4` is expanded by the shell. Would be better to use `shopt -s nullglob` with `for i in *.mp4` instead.

To find all files named `*.mp4`, do `find . -name '*.mp4'`. Note quotation. The `-maxdepth 1` limits found files to only current directory.